# Slow asp.net JIT of usercontrols and masterpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, jit

The website has grown over time, and now the frontpage contains more than 25 usercontrols.

In development it's quite irritating that it taks 70 sec for the first page view (after website is recompiled)

Looking at IIS Failed Request Tracing I can see that each user control takes almost a second to compile:

[image: From track log]

Any ideas how to improve the performance of the compilation?

**Setup**

- .net 4
- iis 7

Thanks!

Comment: Is it using the Web Site template or the Web Application template?

Comment: It's a Web Application template